# htaccess RewriteMode + Hide the original directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So i have installed Laravel and also using htaccess rewrite so i can change the directory for the main domain. It's not the /public_html - its /public_html/examplecom/public

When i open the website: example.com (i have Laravel plugin which redirects me to example.com/en, and the website is fully visible.

The problem is when i try to open: example.com/examplecom/public ... it doesn't hide and return to example.com. It's redirecting to example.com/examplecom/public/en (the Laravel redirect).

So the htaccess code i'm using is this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/examplecom/public/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /examplecom/public/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ examplecom/public/index.php [L]
```

Can someone help? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it... i made it with PHP...

For those who have the same problem:

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (preg_match('|/examplecom/public/(.*)|i', $page)) {
    preg_match('|/examplecom/public/(.*)|i', $page, $exit);
    exit(header('Location: /'.$exit[1]));
}
```